# Are there any nagios plugins or tools for viewing performance reports in a cool way?

Tags: nagios

We have Nagios monitoring our web servers, mail servers and network devices, I was wondering if anyone would recommend a good plugin or tool that uses Nagios data to create clear perfomance reports on hosts and services in a presentable way. What I have in mind is graphs, charts and so forth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[pnp](http://docs.pnp4nagios.org/pnp-0.6/start) is a good solution for your requirements. it is based on rrd and can generate nice graphs. the graphs can also be exported to pdfs.

Answer (score 0):

Just so we're clear, Nagios itself does state monitoring. If you're using plugins that support providing extended information, then you can pull that data from the results of the plugins.

There's a piece of software for Cacti that uses Nagios plugins to create data that I'm considering using. It's NPC, or Nagios Plugins for Cacti ( http://trac2.assembla.com/npc/ ). I have not used it, so can't speak to the performance or anything, but it may be what you're looking for.

If you want to read the raw data yourself, check your configuration for the status log file (typically /var/nagios/status.log or /usr/local/nagios/var/status.log).

Answer (score 0):

The best tool I've found for graphing performance data is [Munin](http://munin.projects.linpro.no/) - it doesn't use the Nagios data directly, but tracks most of the variables that a standard Nagios installation monitors.  Munin is very easy to set up and extend.

Answer (score 0):

I parse nagios logs with a simple perl script that then dumps useful data in to rrds.

Then I use drraw to view the rrds.  It's pretty easy to set up templates in drraw to let you for example: create a template for host CPU load graphs once, and then any new hosts you add automatically show up on a dashboard.

Nagios has some built in dump to rrd plugins, but they all felt bulky to me and I found it easiest just to walk the logs.